# MySQL Substring after a LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this variable that get from a POST command [passing thru the SESSION] --> $ark = 123456-78

I would like to keep eveything before "-" so 123456 to make my research.

I tought that using Subtring will work so i tried this :

This is my request :

```
$req = "SELECT COUNT(`Home`) FROM `users` WHERE `Home` LIKE('$ark')";
```

What I tried with no excpected results:

```
$req = "SELECT COUNT(`Home`) FROM `users` WHERE `Home` LIKE FLOOR('$ark')";
```

and

```
$req = "SELECT COUNT(`Home`) FROM `users` WHERE `Home` LIKE SUBSTRING('$ark',6)"
```

Any idea where I made a mistake ?

Edit: Finally I found the solution using SUBSTRING_INDEX()

```
$req = "SELECT COUNT(`Home`)FROM `users` WHERE `Home` LIKE SUBSTRING_INDEX('%$ark%','-','1')";
```

Thank you all for your help
Rflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one. Hope it should worked.

```
$req = "SELECT COUNT(`Home`) FROM `users` WHERE `Home` LIKE concat('%', SUBSTRING('$ark',6), '%')";
```

Comment: @Rflow well you should choose one of the right answers and mark it as accepted. it will help other users to find the right solution easily. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If LIKE clause is provided without a wildcard character it simply works like equal to operator.
So when you try
`where home LIKE SUBSTRING('$ark',6)`, is nothing but same as
`where home = '123456'` which is not true in your case.
So you have to use wildcard characters to match your data
`where home LIKE concat('%', SUBSTRING('$ark',6), '%')` (you can skip first % if you know that 123456 is not in between) which is equal to
`where home LIKE '%123456%'`

Comment: I have understand the utility of concat. However, this is not working in my php script. Maybe because I'm passing the variable thru the session ? If in my previous php page I write 123456 the search will work on the second page. But If I type 123456-78 it will not work ( even with concat and substring). If i use SUBSTRING_INDEX($ark,'-','1')  it works on phpmyadmin but not on the phpscript.

Answer (score 1):

You need `%` as wildcard

```
SELECT COUNT(`Home`) 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `Home` LIKE concat('%', SUBSTRING('$ark',6), '%')
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but that's not working. The 'Home' value is this type: aba/test/123456. In entry I have this 123456-78 and just need 123456 not "-78".

Answer (score 1):

You sould use concat for build the proper like with wildchar

```
$req = "SELECT COUNT(`Home`) FROM `users` WHERE `Home` LIKE concat('%', '$ark' , '%')";
```